# In pandas If we are re-sampling a 1-minute interval data to a 15-minute interval by averaging can we select how to re-sample and assiggn the data

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

Example: When we have data from 7-8 am 1-minute data how to assign data from 7:00-7:15 1-minute to a 15-minute time stamp at 7:15 and how to do the same from 7:00-7:15 am 1-minute data as 15-minute average to 7:00 am timestamp

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right, you can just resample to the inverval you want, for example:

```
In [16]: index = pd.date_range('2019-11-1', '2019-12-1', freq='1T')                                                                             

In [17]: series = pd.Series(np.random.rand(len(index)), index=index)                                                                            

In [18]: series = series.resample('15T').mean()  # Average over 15min intervals
```

Output:

```
In [19]: series.tail()                                                                                                                          
Out[19]: 
2019-11-30 23:00:00    0.392965
2019-11-30 23:15:00    0.521111
2019-11-30 23:30:00    0.563201
2019-11-30 23:45:00    0.564622
2019-12-01 00:00:00    0.762733
Freq: 15T, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

(I cannot comment, thus I add an answer) You can add to the solution of Felipe Lanza the position of the window label, to define "which bin edge label to label bucket with", right or left:

```
series.resample('15min', label='right').mean()
```